# In Shiny the output from the App file is not being showed once I send it to the module file

Tags: r, shiny

The I idea of my app is as follow:

Once I click on the First option of my select input it displays as options this names: `names(mtcars)[1:4]`, if I click on the second option it displays these options: `c('Option A','Option B','Option C','Option D')`.

And then if I click on those names links, bellow is displayed ther names.

The problem:

From the starts it doesnt work well. I receive this *warning* message:

**Warning: Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'**

But once I start to use the App everyhthing works fine.

Can you help me to fix this app?

This is the main app file:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput(inputId = 'selection',
              choices = c('First Option','Second Option'),
              label = 'Select'),

  htmlOutput('options_choice'),

  example_UI('example')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$selection,
               if(input$selection == 'First Option'){

                 output$options_choice <- renderUI({

                   names(mtcars)[1:4] %>% map(~ actionLink(label = paste0(.x),
                                                         inputId = paste0(.x)))

                   })
                 }else{

                   output$options_choice <- renderUI({

                   c('Option A','Option B','Option C','Option D') %>% map(~ actionLink(label = paste0(.x),
                                                                                       inputId = paste0(.x)))
                   })
               })
  

  name <- reactiveVal(observeEvent(input$selection, {
    if (input$selection == 'First Option') {
      "mpg"
    } else{
      "Option A"
    }


  }))

  observeEvent(input$selection,{

    if(input$selection == 'First Option'){

      names(mtcars)[1:4] %>% map(~ observeEvent(input[[.x]],
                                                {
                                                  name(.x)
                                                }))
    }else{

      c('Option A','Option B','Option C','Option D') %>% map(~ observeEvent(input[[.x]],
                                                {
                                                  name(.x)
                                                }))
    }

  })


  example_Server("example", names = name)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And here is the module file:

```
example_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    htmlOutput(ns('name_from_main'))
  )
}

example_Server <- function(id, names) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      output$name_from_main <- renderUI({
        h1(names())
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Any help would be amazing

Comment: `reactiveVal(observeEvent(......` makes no sense. And you should not nest some `observeEvent`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
example_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    htmlOutput(ns('name_from_main'))
  )
}

example_Server <- function(id, names) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      output$name_from_main <- renderUI({
        h1(names())
      })
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectInput(inputId = 'selection',
              choices = c('First Option','Second Option'),
              label = 'Select'),
  
  htmlOutput('options_choice'),
  
  example_UI('example')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(names=NULL, name=NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$selection, {
    if(input$selection == 'First Option') {
      rv$names = names(mtcars)[1:4]
    }else rv$names = c('Option A','Option B','Option C','Option D')
  })
  
  output$options_choice <- renderUI({
    input$selection
    rv$names %>% map(~ actionLink(label = paste0(.x), inputId = paste0(.x)))
  })

  observe({
    if (input$selection == 'First Option') {
      rv$name = "mpg"
    } else{
      rv$name = "Option A"
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$selection, {
    
    lapply(rv$names, function(x){
      observeEvent(input[[x]], {
        rv$name = as.character(x)
      })
    })
    
  })
  
  example_Server("example", names = reactive(rv$name))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```